# create array from selected items in an array of Fruit items

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with items and an array with indices to delete from the first array:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]    
let indicesToDelete = [4, 8]

let reducedArray = indicesToDelete.reverse().map { array.removeAtIndex($0) }
reducedArray  // prints ["i","e"]
```

What if my array looks like this:

```
class Fruit{
let colour: String
let type: String
init(colour:String, type: String){
    self.colour = colour
    self.type = type
    }
}

var arrayFruit = [Fruit(colour: "red", type: "Apple" ),Fruit(colour: "green", type: "Pear"), Fruit(colour: "yellow", type: "Banana"),Fruit(colour: "orange", type: "Orange")]
let indicesToDelete = [2,3]
```

If I just use the above code I get an error.

```
let reducedArray = indicesToDelete.reverse().map { arrayFruit.removeAtIndex($0) }//////    error here
```

My questions is that the fruitArray is made out of objects and I do not know how to adjust the code in above line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduced array is not the result of `map` but the original array, i.e. `arrayFruit`. I would suggest not using `map` but `forEach`, and write it like this:

```
class Fruit{
    let colour: String
    let type: String
    init(colour:String, type: String){
        self.colour = colour
        self.type = type
    }
}

var arrayFruit = [Fruit(colour: "red", type: "Apple" ),Fruit(colour: "green", type: "Pear"), Fruit(colour: "yellow", type: "Banana"),Fruit(colour: "orange", type: "Orange")]
let indicesToDelete = [2,3]

indicesToDelete.sort(>).forEach { arrayFruit.removeAtIndex($0) }
arrayFruit // [{colour "red", type "Apple"}, {colour "green", type "Pear"}]
```

Comment: sorry, Matt, I am not specific enough. in the fruitArray I just want to delete e.g. item 1 (Apple)

Comment: well, you are right, it works and I like forEach better since I can understand it better than map